# Authenticating Azure Storage with system assigned Identity from Azure Functions

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-managed-identity

I want to use system assigned Identity from Azure Functions to authenticate and read from storage account. I got the following code for .NET. I was looking for equivalent code in Java. Thanks in advance.

```cs
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("WebHook-Func")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/");
        TokenCredential creds = new TokenCredential(accessToken);

        log.LogInformation($"Token: {accessToken}");

        StorageCredentials storageCreds = new StorageCredentials(creds);

        try
        {
            CloudBlobClient client = new CloudBlobClient(new StorageUri(new Uri("https://<storageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net")), storageCreds);
            CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("fltd");
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("shopping.txt");

            string content = await blob.DownloadTextAsync();

            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"File contents: {content}");
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult($"Exception when calling web hook: {ex.StackTrace} {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code seems to be correct. What problem you're facing?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodia, I am looking equivalent Java implementation for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access Azure blob in Azure function with  system assigned Identity, please refer to the following steps

1. [Create Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function)
2. [Enable system assigned Identity the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#add-a-system-assigned-identity)
   [image]
3. Assign role(Storage Blob Data Contributor) fo the MSI at the storage account level
   [image]
   [image]
4. Sdk

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-client-authentication</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
            <version>8.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

4. Code

```
 public HttpResponseMessage run(@HttpTrigger(name = "req",methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request, ExecutionContext context) throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, IOException {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
        AppServiceMSICredentials msiCredentials = new AppServiceMSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
        String token = msiCredentials.getToken("https://storage.azure.com/");
        context.getLogger().info("000000000000" + token);
       
        String accountName = "jimtestdiag924";
        StorageCredentialsToken credentials = new StorageCredentialsToken(accountName, token);
        CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);
        CloudBlobClient client = account.createCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = client.getContainerReference("testupload");
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("hello.txt");
        String content = blob.downloadText();
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("The file content :" + content).build();
    }
```

[image]